# What I decorated has been printed all around

Tags: riddle, word

What I decorated has been printed all around;
if read in the wrong way, I burn every object down.
Some of you may see me right now, depending on your device;
and I'm created and placed by keen, observant eyes.

What am I?

**Hint:**

> I'm thin and light, you overlook;
> I gave the words the shape they'd took.
> Where there are texts, I am of use:
> Inscriptions, books, and all the news.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you are

> A serif

What I decorated has been printed all around;

> Serifs are the small lines at the top or bottom of letters. They are mostly there for decoration, but you find them in all kinds of texts all around.

if read in the wrong way, I burn every object down.

> 'Serif' read backwards makes 'fires'. That tend to burn things down.

Some of you may see me right now, depending on your device;

> Serifs are common on computer screens. Some fonts omits them though.

and I'm created and placed by keen, observant eyes.

> A designer might want to use fonts with serifs to make the texts look better. But he must be observant to see if it helps improve the  readability of the text or not.

Comment: If this isn't the correct answer, I'm bamboozled

Comment: Exactly! every line is correct

Answer (score 2):

Are you

> a magnifying glass?

*What I decorated has been printed all around;*

> This is the line I'm least sure about. Maybe things with a magnifying-glass icon on them that are printed all around?

*if read in the wrong way, I burn every object down.*

> Don't try to "read" the sun with a magnifying glass, or you'll start a fire.

*Some of you may see me right now, depending on your device;*

> When viewing any Stack Exchange page, there's a magnifying glass at the top of the screen in the search bar.

*and I'm created and placed by keen, observant eyes.*

> By keen observant eyes *for* less keen observant eyes!

Comment: Hey I really like this answer, you made some solid points I've never thought of

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you are an

> Atom

What I decorated has been printed all around;

> Atoms are everywhere

if read in the wrong way, I burn every object down.

> if used in the wrong way, you have an atomic bomb

Some of you may see me right now, depending on your device;

> You can see an atom with a microscope

and I'm created and placed by keen, observant eyes.

> God is keen and observant

Answer (score 0):

Is the word

> Ink?

What I decorated has been printed all around;

> Ink is printed and can have many different colours to decorate

if read in the wrong way, I burn every object down.

> Ink can be read a 'kin', a word for relationships. If you have a bad relationship, your life can be destroyed

Some of you may see me right now, depending on your device;

> See this sentence? It is 'printed' into the screen

and I'm created and placed by keen, observant eyes.

> *I might need a little help here*